# Wanting to return individual variables for different "types" in the Google Map json object

Tags: add-on, google-maps-for-ee

Using the GMaps geocoder field and using the parse parameter on the template to return the data stored in it.

Is there a way to access just each address componoent individually? For instance, I want to return the zipcode only.

`{types}` does not appear to be a loop. I also tried `{types:var}` and no dice.

https://objectivehtml.com/google-maps/fieldtype#parse

This is what the JSON object looks like from Google Maps API:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#JSON

```
{retailers_geolocation parse="markers"}

    {markers}

        {marker:address_components}

            {short_name}

        {/marker:address_components}

    {/markers}

{/retailers_geolocation}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is coming in 3.3, but it's not 100% ready for release. The main issue is that each locality has different address components and meanings. So my current example is US based (because that's where I am).

The API will look something like:

```
{your_field:address_component type="zipcode"}
{your_field:address_component type="city"}
{your_field:address_component type="address"}
{your_field:address_component type="state"}
```

There are config variables so you can define your own locality, but of course there are no docs for this yet and has not been very well tested (outside of me). There is no ETA on this, but I know 3.3 will not be in the next several weeks or month. It's several months out. I you want the beta preview to use without docs I am happy to send it to you. Email support@objectivehtml.com